# HTML - Text in the center of a webpage

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I am quite new to website-development and am working on a new website with a friend. I have come up with this code so far, but for some reason the text is on one different line. How do I make this text be stretched out along ONE line across the page? Thanks!

Code (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
<title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
<div class="center">
  <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
</div>

.center{
    position:absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left:50%
    top:50%
}
</head>
```

Code (CSS)

```
body {background-image: url("csgocarryback.jpg"); background-size: 100%;}

h1 {color:white; text-align:center; font-size:50px}

div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: none;

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get your text in the center of your WebPage:

```css
.text-center {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, the CSS in your HEAD tag should be in STYLE tags and the DIV should *not* be in the HEAD part at all, it belongs into the BODY section.

Your CSS .center{} sets the width of the DIV to 50px, of course that will not put all the text into one line.

This would be valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
    <title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>

    <style>
    .center{
        position:absolute;
        height: 50px;
    /*  width: 50px;  */
        left:50%
        top:50%
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. Content and related elements cannot be inside the `<head>` element. Your CSS also needs to be contained within `<style>` tags. It won't be applied unless it is.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you really want to use fixed positioning for centering.  Using margin: 0 auto or an inline-block div with a parent with text-align:center are both better bets.  However, if you want to center with fixed positioning, here is what you do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
        <title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url("csgocarryback.jpg"); 
                background-size: 100%;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align:center; 
                font-size:50px;
            }
            div {
                height: 200px;
                width: 400px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-top: -100px;
                margin-left: -200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center your `<h1>` (header 1) like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">

<head>
    <title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Or with the code you have supplied this would be the correct way.
.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
<head> 
    <title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

.css file:

```
body {background-image: url("csgocarryback.jpg"); background-size: 100%;}

h1 {color:white; text-align:center; font-size:50px}

div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

center{
    position:absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left:50%
    top:50%
}
```

Comment: You, too, are supplying invalid HTML that is also using obsolete elements (`<center>`). Don't do that.

Comment: <center> works the same way as <html> any browser from 1996 to present will understand it, of course its best to use your css and class so you can be sure center is displayed how you would like. By just using <center> you leave it up to the clients browser to determine the minor settings like you see in your css center { code }

Comment: "It works" is never a reason to use obsolete elements that may be removed from browser usage without notice: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: Rob thanks for that link, never really seen all of these very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a re-write of your code and commented the ones not needed. I simplified some of the css you added and place it as a inline style. Paste the entire code to see how it renders, let me know if this works. and to make it external css copy everything inside the `style` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("http://CSGOCarry.com/csgocarryback.jpg"); 
    background-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color:black; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-size:50px;
}

div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: none;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    /*top: 50%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
    /*margin-top: -100px;*/
    /*margin-left: -200px;*/
}
.center{
    /*position:absolute;*/
    /*height: 50px;*/
    /*width: 50px;*/
    /*left:50%;*/
    /*top:50%;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
<title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
<div class="center">
  <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
</div>

</head>


<body>
    <div class="center"> <h1>This is a header</h1> <p> velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML being inside the head element is invalid.

Comment: yeah what I did was I wanted him to be able to test immediately or cut/paste it into his external file...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
  
    <title>CSGOCarry.com | Win Big!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csgositecss.css">
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center">
        <h1>Welcome to CSGOCarry</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```